# Accessing python class variables in an ansible playbook without passing as an command line argument or storing in a file/vault file

Tags: python, ansible

```
=======================================================================================
main.py
=======================================================================================
from first import *
from variables import *
import subprocess
print("pass from main:", Vars.password)
subprocess.Popen("ansible-playbook -i localhost ansible_playbook.yml", shell=True)

.

=======================================================================================
first.py
=======================================================================================

from variables import *
import getpass
pass_ = getpass.getpass("Enter password:")
Vars.password= pass_


=======================================================================================
ansible_playbook.yml
=======================================================================================
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
      pass_ : "abcd"   
  tasks:
  - debug: var=pass_


=======================================================================================
variables.py
=======================================================================================
class Vars():
        password = None
```

When we run main.py, password is entered by user and that gets stored in variables.py as a part of main.py and if we run the ansible playbook in the main.py same class variable password need to be accessed in a ansible script without passing as command line argument or storing in a file or vault file, how can we do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use [playbook prompts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html)?

Otherwise for executing ansible playbooks from python, have a look at the [python api](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_api.html#python-api-example) ([PlaybookExecutor](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/cli/playbook.py)).